# Making a sql statement with multiple grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a summary report based off my database. It must be grouped by location by week by year and I want to total the amount of orders in that grouping.

It needs to look something like:

```
Year    Week    Location    Total Amount
2014    1       Atlanta     22,000 
2014    1       Schaumberg  32,566 
2014    1       Dallas      32,567 
2014    1       New York    32,356 
2014    2       Atlanta     22,000 
2014    2       Schaumberg  32,566 
2014    2       Dallas      32,567 
2014    2       New York    32,356
```

My table (system_order) structure is setup like this:

```
Order   Amount  Location    Week    Year
1       1895    Schaumberg  1       2014
2       1295    Atlanta     1       2014
3       1895    Atlanta     1       2014
4       1895    New York    1       2014
5       1495    Dallas      2       2014
6       1695    Schaumberg  2       2014
7       1895    Schaumberg  2       2014
8       1895    Dallas      2       2014
9       1895    New York    2       2014
```

Can this be done in one sql statement?

Comment: You have a column called 'order'?

Comment: No none of those are table column names, they are the names I gave to the columns for the sql results. I don't post real db names, table names, or column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Year, Week, Location, sum(Amount) as 'Total Amount'
FROM [system_order] 
GROUP BY Location, Week, Year
```

Comment: Thought for sure i'd have to do a sql statement in a sql statement. Thanks a bunch man

Answer (score 1):

I have not testest. Bus this should work.

```
select sum(amount), year,week,location
from (system_order)
group by Location, week, year
order by sum(amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to put the rows you selected into the group by clause. The exception is if they are in an aggregate function in the select clause.

This right here should work.

```
Select Year
       ,Week
       ,Location
       ,sum(amount) as 'Total_Amount'
from (system_order)
group by Year
       ,Week
       ,Location
```